# Why there are two 'were's in one sentence?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, ellipsis

> But, as time went on, it became increasingly obvious that many of the programs were not available, and the ones that were were written in a particularly obscure form of BASIC.
>
> ([Probability Theory: The Logic of Science](http://books.google.com/books?id=tTN4HuUNXjgC&pg=PR17&lpg=PR17&dq=%22But+,as+time+went+on,it+became+increasingly+obvious+that+many%22&source=bl&ots=H4QqsAGyT8&sig=_5eV4bZauVINHt6OktkKB-vFIus&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=r4dLUpPJKYfWiAK46IDwDQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22But%20%2Cas%20time%20went%20on%2Cit%20became%20increasingly%20obvious%20that%20many%22&f=false) by E. T. Jaynes)

What is the effect of the first *were* in *that were were written in* and what is the effect of the second *were*?

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! I notice that your transcription of the sentence seems to have some problems. The spaces don't appear in the right place near commas, and I'm pretty sure it should say "form *of* BASIC". Is that right? In addition, it would be very helpful if you would give a link to where you found this quote. Can you please edit your question so that we can more easily answer it? Thank you!

Comment: It appears to be from [*Probability Theory: The Logic of Science*](http://books.google.com/books?id=tTN4HuUNXjgC&pg=PR17&lpg=PR17&dq=%22But+,as+time+went+on,it+became+increasingly+obvious+that+many%22&source=bl&ots=H4QqsAGyT8&sig=_5eV4bZauVINHt6OktkKB-vFIus&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=r4dLUpPJKYfWiAK46IDwDQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22But%20%2Cas%20time%20went%20on%2Cit%20became%20increasingly%20obvious%20that%20many%22&f=false) by E. T. Jaynes, page xvii.

Answer (score 29):

The first of the two consecutive *were*s is the verb in the relative clause headed by *that*; you are called upon to infer its complement, which is the same as the complement of the previous *were*. The second is the verb in the main clause

```
SUBJECT:   Many of the programs   
PREDICATE: were not available
                        ↓
 and                    →→→→→→→→→→→→
                                    ↓
SUBJECT:   the ones that were [available]
PREDICATE: were written in a particularly obscure form of BASIC.
```

Comment: +1 for the diagram!  I may try to write answers in this format in the future... :-)

Answer (score 11):

In this sentence:

> But, as time went on, it became increasingly obvious that many of the programs **were not available**, and the ones that **were [available]** were written in a particularly obscure form of BASIC.

The author has chosen not to repeat the word *available*.  If we put that word back in, and if we mark the **subject** and **predicate**, it might make more sense:

> ( the ones that were [**available**] )<sub>*subj*</sub> ( were written in a particularly obscure form of BASIC )<sub>*pred*</sub>

This clause is talking about the programs that *were* available.  These programs were written in a particularly obscure form of BASIC.

Answer (score 8):

Try reading the sentence with a comma after the first were like --> "were, were written". That should make the meaning more clear.

Comment: +1.  Although it's usually **not** acceptable to put a comma between a subject and verb like this, this is an exception.  See *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Chapter 20, Section 3.2.4, under the heading "Between subject and verb: comma under exceptional circumstances".